# AWS Linux 2 --bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): Error

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

I am getting the following errors on my AWS AMI Linux 2 it started happening, and I'm not sure why. I also can not run sudo yum update. The error is below.

```
https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_COLLATE: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_MESSAGES: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_NUMERIC: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_TIME: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I am using AWS Linux and this fixed my issue:

```
sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```